# Issue with scroll in combo Box in Codenameone

Tags: combobox, codenameone

## I am creating one combo box with 10 element using codenameone but when i am running it in simulator ,scroll property is not working.

### here is the piece of code what i have tried.Can anyone give me solution.

```
final ComboBox combo=new ComboBox();

         combo.addItem("Event1");
         combo.addItem("Event2");
         combo.addItem("Event3");
         combo.addItem("Event4");
         combo.addItem("Event5");
         combo.addItem("Event6");
```

Comment: You press the popup then try to scroll within the dialog or something else?

Comment: Actually i have a form(layout is border layout) and inside that form i have a container (layout is box layout). I added one combo box with 20 items and 2 buttons(register and unregister).when i will press any button one dialog box will pop us and it will show the message that item 1-12 in combo box has been successfully registered/unregisted.But problem is that when i am trying to select item in below part of combo box ,i am not able to scroll the scroll-bar.do u get my problem ??

Comment: Did you add that container to the center? Please explain the full layout in the question. The combo box has nothing to do with it.

Comment: i am using box layout for the container and border layout for form and i am adding the container to center only. here is the code.  <form.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, demoappContainer)>

Comment: Please post the code you used for the layout of the container above. Make sure you enabled scroll Y on the container.